There is a largest rational number $q$ whose square is less than $2$
We are currently studying logic in math. I am stuck on this question.

Write the following statements in quantifier notation and in words. Make sure to use clear brackets.
There is a largest rational number $q$ whose square is less than $2$.

What I have done is the following:
$$
\exists q \in \mathbb{Q} : (q^2<2 \land (\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} : (r^2 < 2 \implies r \le q)))
$$
My reasoning with the expression $(\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} : (r^2 < 2 \implies r \le q))$ was this: to say that $q$ is the greatest number whose square is less than $2$, we must ensure that there is no rational number greater than $q$ that also meets the criterion $r^2 < 2.$
Assuming that there is a $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r^2 < 2$, initially I just stated that if $r^2 < 2$, then it must follow that $r < q$, and $r$ cannot be greater without violating the implication. However, now I'm not so sure.
I then thought about doing something with $q = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}, b \neq 0, 1$, and $a$ and $b$ are co-prime, but I think this might be wrong, and I have no idea how to properly construct this.

thank you, i have corrected those. But now with the $r\le q$ part, my statement would make no sense since q won't be the greatest number.

You can either say that for any $r\in\Bbb Q$ if $r^2<2$ then $r\le q$ of that if $r^2<2$ and $r\ne q$ then $r<q$. Both mean that $q$ is the greatest rational having a square less that $2$

does that mean $\exists q \in \mathbb{Q} : (q^2<2 \land (\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} : ((r^2 <2\land r\neq q) \implies r < q)))$ would be correct?

Yes. That is the proposal you must write the negation for.

Your proposal is already correct; what do you feel is wrong with it? And there's no need to define what rational numbers are: this is merely a translation exercise, not a real analysis exercise.

The formula in the question is correct.
